# Shopping Cart and item class in python, issue with accessing objects from one class and using them in another

Tags: python, list, class, loops, methods

Attempting to create a program in python 3 that takes object(s) created from one class `item` to another, `shoppingCart`. The idea is to create a list of objects created by the `item` class using the `shoppingCart`class, while still being able to access attributes of the `item` class such as price and quantity.

```
class item:
    def __init__(self,n,p,q):
        self.name = n
        self.price = p
        self.quantity = q
    def show(self):
        z = (str(self.name))
        print(z)
        self1 =("$")+(str(self.price))
        print(self1)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def getPrice(self):
        return ("$") + str(self.price)
    def getQuantity(self):
        return self.quantity

class shoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = []
    def show(self):
        print(self.items)
    def addItem(self,item):
        if item not in self.items:
            self.items.append(item)
        else:
            item.q += 1
    def deleteItem(self,item):
        if item in self.items:
            self.items.remove(item)
        else:
            return print("Not in Cart")
    def checkOut (self):
        total = 0
        for i in self.items:
            price = i[1]
            total += price
        return total
item1 = item("Chocolate",5 ,3)
item2 = item("Bacon",15,1)
item3 =  item("Eggs",2,5)
c = shoppingCart([])
c.addItem(item1)
c.addItem(item2)
c.addItem(item3)
c.show()
print ("You have 3 items in your cart for a total of" (c.checkOut()))
c.removeItem(item3)
print ("You have 2 items in your cart for a total of" (c.checkOut()))
```

The above code currently creates two errors, firstly, the c.show is printing the IDs of the objects appended to the shopping cart. In addition, the `checkOut` method creates an error regarding `price = i[1]` saying that the `item` object does not support indexing. Alternate solutions to this problem that still bares some resemblance to my original code will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `c.show()` prints the list, but you haven't defined `__str__` or `__repr__` for your classes, so you're stuck with the default representation. Try e.g.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

Then you can:

```
print(map(str, self.items))
```

Alternatively, use your `item.show`:

```
for i in self.items:
    i.show()
```

Second, in `checkOut`, `i` is an `item`, which you can't index into. If you want its price, use dot notation: `i.price`.

Comment: Slightly confused on the def __str__(self): part - where exactly do I put it, and what does it do? Should it replace the show method? In addition, changing i[1] to i.price gives an error that the str object is not callable.

Comment: "str object not callable" error probably occured because of your last two print statements. try this `print ("You have 3 items in your cart for a total of %d" % c.checkOut())`

Comment: `__str__` is a [magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#representations), you out it with the other instance methods. @Lafexlos is correct about your other error.

Comment: Thank you so much jonrsharpe and @Lafexlos. I don't exactly understand magic methods as of yet so I used the for i in self.items instead, which works perfectly.